# Matching Layers on generative NFTs - solidity/js/react/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, solidity

When layering an NFT to produce generative art, how do I ensure that different sizes of clothing are matched against the correct body type / size?
For reference, see MetaHero universe: one mint controls generation of 3 distinct body types who all are matched with the correct sized clothing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In games one common way to do this is to generate assets for each body type. For example if you have a black trench coat you need 3 different assets to represent it - one for each body type.

Internally the data structure representing the clothing does not care. Internally it's just a trench coat. Only when it comes to render the character do you need to fetch the correct trench coat based on body type.

This is the same as with the real world. If you join a club you may need a uniform. Club rules just consider wearing the uniform as a requirement - all uniforms are the same in theory. But when you actually go and buy the uniform you have to pick a size.